# How to make this pop up layer in the middle of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the Joe Pilot Chapter 1, link at the bottom right, pop up into a new layer in the middle of the page as wide as the tall as the main body container, but i cant seem to figure out it,

the link is http://alanmcteer.com/v2/

and the jsfiddle.net/vmsfyqz2/

Can someone please help me out? it seems to be popping in the the bottom part only?

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/atrifan/bedtvt6v/

Comment: If you are set on a Pop-Up see Jack's answer. But I agree with Alexis. Use a jQuery 'onclick' handler and change the main content to display the chapter. Much cleaner and won't get blocked.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that SRing, i would love to make it look cleaner. But I'm afraid I don't quite understand how to. I'm just starting out with HTML/CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the position to `fixed` on `.black_overlay` and `.white_content` so that the body is the parent element.

I updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmsfyqz2/1/

Answer (score 1):

- easies way would be to take the "light"-container and set it directly under the body-node. this should do it.
- you are using jquery, why not implementing the "onclick" handler with jQuery ?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that Alexis.